# display data based on pass value id

Tags: reactjs

i want to display data based on its id. i have 2 page, app.js and display.js. in app.js i already display a table and clickable data to link to display.js. but i cant display data n display.js based on its id. i use API to get this all data and data in display.js is looping all data on result json and not only by id that i click on app.js.

can anyone helpme to pass the id from app.js to display.js and not loop data on display.js?

here's my code

App.js

```
              class App extends React.Component {
                constructor(props) {
                  super(props);
                this.state = {
                  data: [],
                  errors: null,
                  isLoading: true
                };
              }

              getData = async () => {
                const option = {
                  url:api/url
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                  },
                  data: {
                    "data": {
                      "data": "111111"
                    },
                    "encrypt": 0
                  }
                };

                axios(option)
              .then(response => {
                  const tableData = response.data.data.map(post => {
                      const {id, name, type} = post;
                      return [
                        <Link to={'/display'}>{id}</Link>, //when i click this it link to display.js and in display.js only display data based on this id
                        <Link to={'/display'}>{name}</Link>, 
                        <Link to={'/display'}>{type}</Link>
                      ];
                  });
              this.setState({
                  data: tableData,
                  isLoading: false
                });
              })
                  );
              }

              componentDidMount() {
                this.getData();
              }


                render() {
                  const columns = ["ID", "Name", "Type"];

                  const options = {
                    filterType: "dropdown",
                    responsive: "scroll",
                    selectableRows:false
                  };

                  return (
                    <div>
                    <center><h3>Table</h3></center><br/>

                    {!isLoading ? (
                                <MUIDataTable
                                data={this.state.data}
                                columns={columns}
                                options={options} 
                              />)
                          : (
                            <p>Loading...</p>
                          )}
                            </div>
                            );

                          }
              }

              export default App
```

display.js

```
        class App extends React.Component {
          // State will apply to the posts object which is set to loading by default
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              data: [],
              isLoading: true,
              errors: null
            };
        }

          // Now we're going to make a request for data using axios
          getData = async () => {
            const option = {
              url:api/url
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
              },
              data: {
                "data": {
                  "data": "111111"
                },
                "encrypt": 0
              }
            };


            axios(option)
              .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                  data: response.data.data,
                  isLoading: false,
                });
                console.log(response.data);
                const data = JSON.parse(data);
              })

              );
          }


          componentDidMount() {
            this.getData();
        }


          // Putting that data to use
          render() {

            const { isLoading, data} = this.state;
            return (

              <React.Fragment>
                <h3>Data display</h3><br/>
              <div>

                {!isLoading ? (
                  data.map(post => {
                      const {id, name, age, type, gender} = post;

                    return (
                      //from API this data is looping and more than 1, i want to after click id from app.js it will link to this display.js page and only show data based on id
                  <div>
                  <Card>
                  <CardHeader color="info">
                      <h4 >Data </h4>
                    </CardHeader>
                      <CardBody>

                        <div><b>ID</b></div>
                        <div>{id}</div>

                        <div><b>Name</b>
                        <div>{name}</div>

                        <div><b>age</b></div>
                        <div>{age}</div>

                        <div><b>type</b></div>
                        <div >{type}</div>

                        <div><b>gender</b></div>
                        <div>{gender}</div>

                      </CardBody>
                  </Card>

                        <br/>

                        </div>


                      );
                    })
                  ) : (
                    <p>Loading...</p>
                  )}
                </div>
              </React.Fragment>

            );

          }
        }

        export default App;
```

anyone can help to only show page display.js based on id i click in app.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the id within of the clicked row within the link child

`<Link to={{
  pathname: '/display',
  state: {
    data: post
  }
}}></Link>`

and in your display component you can get the id to send with the request
`const { data } = this.props.location.data`

and in your display component you'll get all the clicked row data and you can remove the loop from the render as well as the request

Comment: i just try and it can pass value of id, but cant display age,type based on that id.. and the data still loop on display.js

Comment: in return display data i still declare the id, age and other? or declare the data?